# Accessing Lumen/Laravel URL params

Tags: php, laravel

I guess I'm missing something really obvious here but how do you access URL params in Lumen? I have the following route:

```
$app->get('user/{id}', ['uses' => 'userController@testId']);
```

Then in my user controller I have:

```
public function testId(Request $request) {

    return $request->input('id');
}
```

But the ID is always null what have I missed even in this very basic example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, doesn't matter, as I thought I'm the tool here.

For anyone else (and myself in the future when I land on this page after a Google with the exact same problem next year) the documentation states:

> If your controller method is also expecting input from a route parameter, simply list your route arguments after your other dependencies. For example, if your route is defined like so:
>   `$app->put('user/{id}', 'UserController@update');`
>
> `public function update(Request $request, $id)
>       {
>           //
>       }`

So you need to pass any URL params into the function, they don't appear to be accessible via Lumens $request object.

```
public function testId(Request $request, $id) {

    return $id;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
public function testId(Request $request) {
    return $request->id;
}
```

Comment: That produces the following error Call to a member function parameter() on array

Comment: what you get in `$request->request` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests you can do the following:

```
$app->get('user/{id}', ['uses' => 'userController@testId']);

public function testId(Request $request, $id) {
      //$id is from the path
}
```

The reasoning is that `id` is part of the request path and not the request input